# Jupyter notebook Latex cannot get widebar to work

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex

In Jupyter Notebook, how can I get a bar (representing variable mean) to span the full string in braces?

Python 3.7, if that matters

`$\bar{T_V(C)}$` returns a tiny bar:
[image]

`$\widebar{T_V(C)}$` doesn't seem to work:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\overline`.

```
$\overline{T_V(C)}$
```

[image]